# Lightning Experience User Creating a Permission Set

Tags: permission-sets, lightning-experience

Trying to create a Permission Set for Lightning Experience.  Once I set up the name and API for the permission where do I go to select "Lightning Experience User"  I can't find this anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will go to **system permissions > Lightning Experience User**

The below screenshots should help you

[image]

[image]